# Laravel 5.8: Trying to make a where model by using data pulled from database

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my model:

```
$AVMatchCriteria = device::where([$AVMatch])->get();
```

I am creating the variable $AVMatch by using a foreach loop to run through the entries in my table, below is what it looks like if I echo it out.

```
["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]
```

When running my code I get the following error:

[image]

If i was to however just copy the string in plain text and put it in the model like below it works fine. I'm not sure why its not working but its putting a 0 = in my query somehow and im guessing thats the problem.

```
$AVMatchCriteria = device::where([["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]])->get();
```

Any advice would be great :D

Heres how I am creating the varaible $AVMatch, I know its a little backwards but i was tinkering trying to fix it:

```
    $AVMatch = '';
    $count = 0;

    foreach($AVMatchCriteria as $AV){

    $count++;
    if($count != $AVMatchCriteriaCount){$extra = ',[';}else{$extra = '';}
    $AVMatch = $AVMatch.'"'.$AV->case.'", "'.$AV->operator.'", "'.$AV->filter.'"]'.$extra;

     }

    $AVMatch = '['.$AVMatch;
```

Comment: Is `$AVMatch` a string instead of an array?

Comment: @JoelHinz I have updated question to contain the code for the creation, yes I just made it as string.

Comment: Thanks. You can't supply a string that looks like an array - it won't work. You need to construct an array instead.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I have made an array and its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

echo can output one or more string, not an array.
When you echo an array it should occur an error like `Array to string conversion`. 
But here, after echo the variable $AVMatch you got the result 
`["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]`
That means it's not an array it's a string.

You have to pass an array like 
`[["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]]`
 into where clause.

But you are passing a string looks like 
`'["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "as
d"]'`
Hope you understand.

Comment: Got it working with this,

            $AVMatch = array();

            foreach($AVMatchCriteria as $AV){
            
            $AVMatch[] = array($AV->case, $AV->operator, $AV->filter);

             }

Answer (score 1):

Because you pass into `where` the array which contains array with arrays.

Fix:

```
$AVMatchCriteria = device::where($AVMatch)->get();
```

Comment: Hello, I tried that originally and got this error,

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `devices` where `["category", "=", "Server"],["siteid", "!=", "145228"],["udf8", "=", "asd"]` is null)

Answer (score 0):

After been informed I needed to create an array rather than a string, the code below fixed it.

```
    $AVMatch = array();

    foreach($AVMatchCriteria as $AV){

    $AVMatch[] = array($AV->case, $AV->operator, $AV->filter);

     }
```